# How to access both newly created object in the JAVA stream operation and the current object in the stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, stream

I have a list of objects that I want to process through java stream API.
i need to create another object, SomeData for each of the Component in the list. I also need to access both someData object that was created and the component object later in the stream operations. I need to update the someData object with some complex calculation using the attributes from the component object. How can I achieve this? Below is pseudo code to explain the problem i described here. Thank you in advance for your time!

```
import java.util.List;

class Component{
    String name;
    double price;
}
class SomeData{
    String data;
    double price;
}

public class Test {
    public void processComponent(List<Component> components){
        components.stream()
                .map(component -> (//need to create here SomeData object for each of the component))
                .map(//need to access both someData object that was created and the 'component' object as well)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to transform the result of map(component -> ..) in something like an ImmutablePair, where you put component and SomeData. In the next map use that ImmutablePair.

Answer (score 0):

You can map and perform those complex calculation both in the same map method,

```
components.stream()
    .map(component -> {
        // Create an object and set value from component. 
        SomeData someData = new SomeData();

        // once that is done perform your complex operation here. 

        return someData;
    });
```

I've given an high level context on what can be done. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: OP also needs access to the component object in the next step.

Comment: Then what's the point in using map then?

Comment: If you need both SomeData and Component fields at the end then have class that contains both and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can make Component a property of SomeData:

```
public class SomeData {
    private final Component component;
    String data;
    double price;

    public SomeData(Component component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public Component getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

If SomeData is not a class under your control, or your design doesn’t allow for modifying it, create a class that pairs them.  It can even be a local class;  that is, a class defined inside a method which only exists in the scope of that method:

```
public void processComponent(List<Component> components) {
    class ProcessResult {
        final Component component;
        final SomeData data;

        ProcessResult(Component component,
                      SomeData data) {
            this.component = component;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    components.stream()
        .map(component -> new ProcessResult(component, createDataFrom(component)))
        .map(result -> {
            doStuffWith(result.component);
            doStuffWith(result.data);
            return someOtherValue;
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.toConcurrentMap` inside the `Stream.Collect` method and map each `component` to your `someData`. Then you can stream the `entrySet` of the map and process the data.

```
components.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
        component->component, 
        component-><your someData Object as value>))
        .entrySet().stream()
```

And now you can operate on the entrySet's stream!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).